# php proxy to local mercurial server

Tags: php, proxy, mercurial, localhost

I was wondering is it possible to create a php proxy to a server that listens onlu locally so that the php gateway is public and it directs everything to the server listening on localhost.

This server would be mercurial's hg serve that listens only on 127.0.0.1 and php will do the authentication.

Do You think it's possible to do? Anybody has an idea how to make a general proxy in php so that not only http get works, but also hg push?

I know there are ways to host mercurial repo with auth, but it's on a plug computer and I don't have a lot of space for more apps etc.

Comment: I don’t get it. It sounds like you want to make a home-made proxy which you will expose to the Internet (!!). And you want to do this instead of using Mercurial’s built-in server, which you will also run simultaneously on the same PC. I must be missing something…

Comment: This is just the idea to add authentication via apache to the hg serve with almostno configuration. I'm not sure if it can work at all.

Comment: I see. I’ll add an answer below.

Comment: @all You guys are right. It was much better to set up the chi in comparison th getting in all this trouble setting up a proxy to hg serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to run `hg serve`.

Instead, use `hgweb.cgi` or `hgwebdir.cgi`. These are standard CGI scripts that can be run under Apache. `hgweb.cgi` serves a single repository, and `hgwebdir.cgi` serves multiple repositories. They do not require any special modules to be installed on Apache, and you can use all of Apache’s built-in access-control and authentication mechanisms.

The best reference is [PublishingRepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) on the Mercurial wiki, which explains how to do this and also compares other options, including `ssh`, which requires even less setup.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use PHP, you could use the socket functionalities to do whatever networking you want. (http://ch.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) And you can use fsockopen to connect to whatever you want. You could combine this and use it in a PHP script which you run by console. Use set_time_limit repeatedly to keep your proxy running. You'll need a lot of knowledge and luck to get this done.

But actually it's really WEIRD what you're doing (see other answers and comments). Whatever reason you have for this configuration, it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your php in apache, then you can probably do what you want with php.  Just configure apache to proxy to hgserve (assuming you can't run wsgi or cgi, which is the better solution) and you're set.  I don't think there's anything to add in PHP land that apache and hgserve don't already bring to the table.

But, yes, you could reimplemnt Apache's proxy functionality in PHP, though you'll also need to make sure to include support for RangeRequests, which mercurial uses in some situations.  Don't forget your RFC2616 caching logic (If- headers, Cache-Control, Expires, Last-Modified, etc.) for efficiency...